# How to make an Excel AddIn run an automatic macro?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

(Environment : Office 2021, Excel 16.79.2 (latest), VBA 7.1, macOS Sonoma 14.1.2)

I have written an Excel AddIn (.xlam workbook) that I reference (VBEditor > Tools > References) and use in several other .xlsm workbooks.

That AddIn declares, creates and initialises a certain public variable (myColl) of type Collection. I would like the AddIn routine that initialises (populates) that Collection (via several myColl.Add statements) to run automatically so I do not have to call it from every workbook that uses the AddIn.

I have tried to include in the AddIn a Sub Workbook_Open () routine in hopes that it would run automatically every time a .xlsm workbook using the AddIn opens. No luck, it does not run. I suppose that is because a reference to the AddIn in a .xlsm workbook does not really "Open" the .xlam workbook.

Does anyone know of a means to make the AddIn run a macro automatically when another workbook using the said AddIn opens, without the 'client' workbook having to explicitly invoke it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not very clear what you try accomplishing. "Automatic" may involve a large field... So, if I would say that the respective macro should (automatically) run when specific workbooks (even they are not of Macro-enabled) are opening, will it be a correct understanding? I would like to state that this can be handled even if the respective add-in is referenced in the respective opening workbooks...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Clarification attempt : the macro in the AddIn should run as soon as a macro-enabled workbook referencing it is opened

Comment: Why not initialize the collection when the add-in itself opens?  What is the Collection a collection *of* ?   If you need to respond to workbooks being opened when the add-in is already open, you can use Application Events   - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler

Comment: Please, try applying the solution I posted as an answer and send some feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestions. Will try over the next couple of days. Feedback to follow soon after. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

1. Place the next declaration on top of `ThisWorkbook` code module (in the declarations area):

```
Public WithEvents app As Application
```

2. Place the event (of any opening workbook) and `Open` event in the same (`ThisWorkbook`) code module:

```
Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal wb As Workbook) 'raised on any workbook opening
   If isReferenced(wb) Then
        myMacro wb 'your macro to be called
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     Set app = Application 'to initialize app variable, able to trigger  workbooks open event
End Sub
```

3. Copy the next code in a **standard** module:

```
Function isReferenced(wb As Workbook) As Boolean 'function to check if the add-in is referenced
     Dim i As Long, vbProj As Object
     Set vbProj = wb.VBProject
     For i = 1 To vbProj.references.Count
        If vbProj.references(i).Name = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.Name Then
            isReferenced = True: Exit Function
        End If
     Next i
End Function

Sub myMacro(wb As Workbook) 'your function to be called (use the real one...)
  MsgBox wb.Name & " is opening..."
End Sub
```

4. In any **standard** module, copy the next sub and **RUN** it. It will change the (standard VBAProject) project name in something **specific**, allowing to the above function to find it:

```
Sub VBProjectChangeName()
   ThisWorkbook.VBProject.Name = "myReferencedAddIn" 'use here something eloquent for your add-in...
End Sub
```

Restart your add-in, or manually run `Workbook_Open()` event to initialize `app` (necessary variable) and start playing with it.

If something not clear enough do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: In a situation like this, would the references be needed to reinstated in the opening workbooks or would they automatically adjust (somewhat like when you adjust the U/L-case of variables)?

Comment: @Notus_Panda No, it is not necessary to remove - readd any reference. Excel knows to read the new `VBAProject` name. It keeps it according to its full name. You may test that... With `PERSONAL` workbook, change its `VBAProject' name and then remove the reference, if not needed...

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru , this works. A bit complicated but it does the job. Thanks again

Comment: @nunof34  "Complicated" is a relative concept... It depends on your reference system. I am afraid that it is not possible to have a simpler approach. 1. You need **an event** to trigger the new document opening. Nothing can be simpler as the above one. More complicated, is possible (moving the event in a class). Then, you specified the need to process **only workbooks having a reference to that add-in**. There is no other way to determine this aspect. If you have a list with the respective workbooks, I can adapt the code to use an array keeping their name. You did not say anything about that.

Comment: @nunof34 Then, do you consider that my above solution **did not answer your question**? If so, from which point of view? Complexity? Do you have an example of a  less complex solution? At least, a theoretically description... I would like to remind you that we here, when a suggested solution does what you required in your question, we tick the left code check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the proposed solution works.  If there are more answers you should choose the one liking more. According to your taste.

Comment: Very good solution. Congratulations, you are a master ! Thank you !